# Converting factors (that are numbers) to numerics, without changing the values in my vector

Tags: r, numeric

[image]

So I have this vector that I have called RF, and I have named the data frame that this vector is in RFdf. As we can see, it is a factor. However, when I try to convert it to a numeric in the following way, I lose my RF values... Why is this happening?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTOqV.png)
[image]

Comment: You need to convert to character first: `as.numeric(as.character(RFdf$RF))`

Comment: This is documented in `?factor`, which recommends using `as.numeric(levels(f))[f]` to convert factor `f` to the values.